# How to make Swagger response body json collapsible?

Tags: json, swagger, swagger-ui

The response body of a GET request is shown in Swagger as text in a short window. Since response could be long and because it is json it would be great, if it could be collapsible. So I could find some information much faster.

**How is it possible to show the response body in Swagger as collapsible json?**

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/a/58214636/9530790