# Expand and Collapse Responses in swagger

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

Is it Possible to expand and collapse responses in swagger hub. Only On clicking one type of response it should expand. Because too many responses are consuming lots of space in swagger hub documentation.

[image: need to expand and collapse these responses]

Answer (score 1):

No, the responses are not collapsible.

Feel free to create a feature request in the Swagger UI repository:
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues